# How to compare a '/0' character without it converting to '0'

Tags: assembly, char, type-conversion, integer

I have a homework in my computer architecture class, which is basically to write a code in ASM (32 bits) that removes a specific character from a given string and also gives me the new length (excluding '/0')

- Example: "Hello\n\0"
- Character to remove: 'l'
- Result: "Heo\n\0"
- Length: 4

I can remove any character from the string, however, as a test to see if the program can work in any situation, I have a condition to check if that character to remove is /0, and every time I do so it fails the comparison as it translates '/0' to '0'.
I have read online that when you write '/' it is equal to writing (char) which returns the  in char form.

- Example: (char)1 = '1'

Is there any way I can compare the character '/0' without it converting? I also cannot change the data section as it's part of the rules of the homework, only whats in between '' and "".

Below I present my code

My variable is called remove and it's declared as so:

- remove: .byte '/0'

I then do:

```
mov remove, %cl
cmp $0, %cl
jz goToEnd
```

if the zero flag is set to 0 then i end my function, however it's never the case as %cl receives the value in decimal 48 correspondent to '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have `/0` in a couple places.  forward slash isn't special**; `'/0'` is a 2-byte constant in asm.

Make sure you write `'\0'` if you mean a byte with integer value `0`, the terminator for implicit-length C strings.

(So no, you can't remove it from the end of a string; it *is* the end of a string.  Unless you have explicit-length strings, in which case you remove the last byte by decrementing the length by 1)

Backslash is an escape sequence in C, and also in GAS strings, so you *can* write `'\n'` instead of integer `10`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Normally in GAS syntax you get a zero terminator for strings by using a `.asciz` or `.string` directive, though.

Comment: Yes i was writing **'\0'** in my code but for some reason i wrote **'/0'** here, sorry.
When I compare that **remove** variable to **$0** it returns **false** as **null** is different from **$0**.
Thank you for clarifying, there must be some kind of other test left for me to try then.

Comment: @TiagoMorais: use GDB to check what's actually in memory.  I'm not sure how `'\0'` assembles with GAS.  Also of course make sure you're using `cmpb`  not `cmpl` or something, if you're comparing to memory directly (without loading into a byte register like `%cl` first.  A 0 terminator byte has integer value zero, and `cmp $0, %cl` or `test %cl,%cl` should set ZF, because they are equal.  `test %cl,%cl  / jnz` is what you'd use as the loop condition in a simple naive `strlen` that searches for the terminator 1 byte at a time.